# How to make Chakra UI Drawer component not destroy child components on close?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, user-interface, chakra-ui

I am using Chakra UI Drawer component, and I have nested a form inside of it, which has some really complicated states inside of it. The problem is when I am closing the drawer, the child nested(child) elements inside of the drawer are being destroyed and all the state inside of it is being reset.

I want something like Antd library, which has a prop that you can pass to the drawer as `destroyOnClose = false`  that prevents the Drawer to not destroy its children on close. I want the same thing for Chakra. Is there a way?
like for Antd, reference: https://ant.design/components/drawer#api

the Link to the sample code https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-johnson-cy47rf?file=/src/Form.jsx

When you'll click the "Open" button. It'll open the drawer and inside of it, there will be an input field. When you'll write something inside of it, close the drawer, and reopen it then the value inside of the text field will be gone because the Drawer destroys the child component.

Comment: Hey, did you find solution to this?